# Cordova-plugin-file getFile/getDirectory no callback fire, who can help me

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I found the file plugin could not work.

My function like this:

```
function (filename, fileObj, succCallback) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        fs.root.getFile(filename, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry){
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    if(typeof succCallback === 'function') {
                        succCallback(this.result);
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, myfile.errorHandler);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
}
```

The function do "window.requestFileSystem" succ, but fs.root.getFile not fire the succ/fail function.
I try to debug the "CDVFile.m", and I found the Objective-C Code had be exec over.

the getFile in "CDVFile.m":

```
- (void)getFile:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSString* baseURIstr = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
    CDVFilesystemURL* baseURI = [self fileSystemURLforArg:baseURIstr];
    NSString* requestedPath = [command argumentAtIndex:1];
    NSDictionary* options = [command argumentAtIndex:2 withDefault:nil];

    NSObject<CDVFileSystem> *fs = [self filesystemForURL:baseURI];
    CDVPluginResult* result = [fs getFileForURL:baseURI requestedPath:requestedPath options:options];


    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

AS above, the file plugin (source code "DirectoryEntry.js") succCallback(func win) had not be fire, Neither nor failCallback(func fail). the "DirectoryEntry.js":

```
DirectoryEntry.prototype.getFile = function(path, options, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    argscheck.checkArgs('sOFF', 'DirectoryEntry.getFile', arguments);
    var fs = this.filesystem;
    var win = successCallback && function(result) {
        var FileEntry = require('./FileEntry');
        var entry = new FileEntry(result.name, result.fullPath, fs, result.nativeURL);
        successCallback(entry);
    };
    var fail = errorCallback && function(code) {
        errorCallback(new FileError(code));
    };
    exec(win, fail, "File", "getFile", [this.toInternalURL(), path, options]);
};
```

My XCode version: 7.3 (with iOS SDK 9.3)
My Cordova version : 6.5.0
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.2 "File"

My config.xml had added the preference:

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
```

Have anyone got the same problem, and resolve it? Or give me some tips, thanks!

2017-04-27 additional remarks：

[The debug png why no callback fired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCdyB.png)

I found why no callback fired. But I didnot known why it is "succss and NO_RESULT"...

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, I found that, Because the other one js file conflict. If I add the js file, the file plugin cannot work. And I have no choice but to make  the js file in the iframe page. It can work now.
Perhaps you have the same problem, wish this can help others.